# ngx-leaflet Angular 2 +, preferCanvas: true don't render canvas

Tags: javascript, angular, leaflet

I have to render a lot of marks on the map so i try to use canvas to optimize my app. But in the DOM i see img's again. If i correctly understand the structure should be the same but with canvas inside rendered div's. I use:

```
"leaflet": "^1.4.0"
"@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet": "^5.0.1"
"@types/leaflet": "^1.4.0"
Angular 7
```

My HTML:

```
<div leaflet class="leaflet-map" #divMap
 [leafletOptions]="options"
 [leafletLayersControl]="layersControl"
 (keydown.control)="keyDownHandler($event, divMap)"
 (keyup.control)="keyUpHandler($event, divMap)"
 (leafletMouseDown)="onMouseDown($event)"
 (leafletMouseUp)="onMouseUp($event)"
 (leafletClick)="onMapClick($event)"
 (leafletMapReady)="onMapReady($event)"
 (leafletMapZoom)="onMapZoom($event)">
</div>
```

My Component:

```
export class MapComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  map: L.Map;
  options: MapOptions;
  layersControl: any;
  markers: MapMarker[] = [];
  polygon: Polygon = null;
  userWatch: any;
  firstPoint: any;

  markerOptions = {
    icon: icon({
      iconSize: [25, 41],
      iconAnchor: [13, 41],
      iconUrl: 'assets/marker-icon.png',
      shadowUrl: 'assets/marker-shadow.png'
    })
  };

  constructor(private geocodeService: GeocodeService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.options = {
      preferCanvas: true,
      layers: [
        tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
          maxZoom: 18,
          attribution: ''
        }),
      ],
      zoom: 15,
      center: latLng(53.9266754, 27.6940687)
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Map.preferCanvas option](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#map-prefercanvas) only affects *vector* overlays such as Polygon, Polyline, Circle to be rendered on a Canvas or [`SVG`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#svg) renderer. To render markers via canvas,  [`CircleMarker`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#circlemarker)  could be considered instead of `Marker`, for example:

**app.component.html**

```
<div leaflet class="leaflet-map" #divMap
 [leafletOptions]="options"
 [leafletLayersControl]="layersControl"
 [leafletLayers]="layers">
</div>
```

**app.componennt.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  options: MapOptions;
  layers = [
    circleMarker([ 53.9266754, 27.6940687 ])
];

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.options = {
      preferCanvas: true,
      layers: [
        tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
          maxZoom: 2,
          attribution: ''
        }),
      ],
      zoom: 15,
      center: latLng(53.9266754, 27.6940687)
    };
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-de8ruk)

Comment: So, if I clearly understand you there is no way to render tiles as canvas. And preferCanvas: true or  renderer: L.canvas() options are using for the additional overlay to render markers, polygons and etc. Right?

Comment: That's right, in addition to canvas options (`preferCanvas: true` or `renderer: L.canvas()`) , you need to switch from raster markers to vector layer P.S. Btw, I like your nickname ;)